# Remove dashes and wrap with <li> with javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a "list" that looks like this:

```
-1+ years of experience in End User Support<br>
-Experience re-imaging laptops<br>
-Great customer service experience
```

And I want to turn it into an unordered list.

I wrapped the block in a `<ul></ul>` and then I used this code to remove the `<br>` and wrap with `<li></li>`:

```
$('.entry-content ul').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.html($this.html().replace(/[^\r\n]+/g, '<li>$&</li>'));
});
```

This outputs an unordered list like this:

- -1+ years of experience in End User Support
- -Experience re-imaging laptops
- -Great customer service experience

But I don't know how to remove the dashes, too. I tried doing a second replace function after the first one, like this: `$this.html($this.html().replace((/-/g, ' '));` , but that didn't work.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your posted code doesn't actually remove the `<br>` tags, you just don't see them in the results. I'd replace those, and any "-" after a newline or at the beginning of the text, with newlines, then replace as above.

```js
$('.entry-content ul').each(function() {
  var $this = $(this);

  $this.html(
    $this
      .html()
      .trim()
      .replace(/^-|[\r\n]+-|<br>/g, "\n")
      .replace(/[^\r\n]+/g, '<li>$&</li>')
  );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class=entry-content>
<ul>
-1+ years of experience in End User Support<br>
-Experience re-imaging laptops<br>
-Great customer service experience
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked, but I noticed a downvote. I'm still learning, so I don't know why. Can someone explain what the problem is?

Comment: I'm curious, too, but downvotes are seldom explained. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Ah, thank you. I totally missed that the `<br>` remained in the source with my original code. Thank you for noticing that. Aside from it being poor formatting to leave the `<br>`, do you think there is any benefit to performance in leaving it there, rather than performing the trim function?

Comment: The odds are very low that either one would be significantly faster than the other.

Comment: Thanks. I've chosen this answer.

Answer (score 2):

```js
var str = str = "-Experience re-imaging laptops";

console.log(str.replace(/^-/, ''));
```

Comment: Thanks. I ran a second 'each' function for the $('.entry-content li') and then used your string replacement. Is this the most efficient way (two separate functions)?

Comment: I don't think it's the most efficient, but trying to replace both the `<br>` at the end and the `-` at the beginning with one regex would probably look ugly in the code.