# Conditionally wrap lines in <li> tags and remove first character

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

Using the following html, I need to wrap an `<li>` tag around each line that starts with a dash, strip the dash, and then wrap the whole list in a `<ul>` tag.

```
<div class="json-content">
This line doesn't have a dash
This line also doesn't have a dash 
-An unordered list should start here because the line starts with a dash
-This line starts with a dash and has some dashes-in-the-middle
-Another line that starts with a dash
And another a line that doesn't have a dash.
</div>
```

I was using the code below ([based on an earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55693827/remove-dashes-and-wrap-with-li-with-javascript-jquery)) to achieve this, but when there is other non-dashed text in the div, it's adding an `<li>` tag around those lines, too. I know part of the problem is that it's stripping the dash first, but I've tried using a regex tester to modify it and I just can't figure it out. How can I achieve this?

```
 $('.json-content').each(function() {
      var $this = $(this);

      $this.html(
        $this
          .html()
          .trim()
          .replace(/^-|[\r\n]+-/g, "\n")
          .replace(/[^\r\n]+/g, '<li class="item">$&</li>')    
          );
          $(this).find('li.item').wrapAll( "<ul class='json-list' />");  
    });
```

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9xd2vacj/2/

The end result should look like this:

> This line doesn't have a dash
>  This line also doesn't have a dash
>
> - An unordered list should start here because the line starts with a dash
> - This line starts with a dash and has some dashes-in-the-middle
> - Another line that starts with a dash
>
> And another a line that doesn't have a dash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could append a hyphen `^[ \t]*-.*` to match the lines which start with a hypen. Then capture the list item in a capturing group and match 0+ times a whitespace char and a hyphen.

```
(<li class="item">)\s*-
```

In the replacement use an empty string.

You code might look like:

```
$('.json-content').each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.html(
        $this
            .html()
            .trim()
            .replace(/^[ \t]*-.*/gm, '<li class="item">$&</li>')
            .replace(/(<li class="item">)\s*-/g, "$1")
    );
    $(this).find('li.item').wrapAll("<ul class='json-list' />");
});
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ztudv6a7/)

```js
$('.json-content').each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.html(
        $this
            .html()
            .trim()
            .replace(/^[ \t]*-.*/gm, '<li class="item">$&</li>')
            .replace(/(<li class="item">)\s*-/g, "$1")
    );
    $(this).find('li.item').wrapAll("<ul class='json-list' />");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="json-content">
    This line doesn't have a dash
    This line also doesn't have a dash
    -An unordered list should start here because the line starts with a dash
    -This line starts with a dash and has some dashes-in-the-middle
    -Another line that starts with a dash
    And  a line that doesn't start with a dash but has-one in the middle.
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I tested this out and it was great except if there is a hyphen in a line that doesn't *start* with a hyphen. See the last line in this fiddle. It's removing the words after the first hyphen: https://jsfiddle.net/73xws6c9/

Comment: @LBF I have updated the post a few minutes ago. It should be ok now. See https://jsfiddle.net/3b5qjma9/

Comment: Thanks! That's closer, but it's wrapping the last line in an li tag. That line doesn't start with a hyphen, so it shouldn't be a list item.

Comment: @LBF Ah I see, now it should be correct. https://jsfiddle.net/ztudv6a7/ I have updated my answer.

Comment: That's it, thanks. Seeing the progession of the regex changes helped me learn a little more about how that works. Regex has always baffled me, but I'm starting to understand the patterns. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You may combine:

- [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)
- [.html( function )](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html-function)

```js
$('.json-content').html(function (idx, oldhtml) {
    return oldhtml.replace(/\n *-([^\n]*)/g, function(match, p1) {
        return '<li>' + p1 + '</li>';
    })
}).find('li').wrapAll("<ul/>");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="json-content">
    This line doesn't have a dash
    This line also doesn't have a dash
    -An unordered list should start here because the line starts with a dash
    -This line starts with a dash and has some dashes-in-the-middle
    -Another line that starts with a dash
    And another a line that doesn't have a dash.
</div>
```